# X:Static doesn't work in TextBlock. (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

I just started learning WPF, and a problem arose. X:Static does not display the value from the .resx file, just writes the line itself. There are no errors in the console.

```
        <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Padding="15, 0, 0, 0" FontSize="39.75" FontFamily="{StaticResource LeagueGothic}" Foreground="White">
            {x:Static language:Lang.found_bug}
        </TextBlock>
```

At the same time, it's just not displayed in TextBlock.

Full file listing

```
<Window x:Class="YandereSimulatorLauncher2.Popups.ReportLauncherBug"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:YandereSimulatorLauncher2.Popups"
    xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:YandereSimulatorLauncher2.Controls"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    xmlns:language="clr-namespace:YandereSimulatorLauncher2.Properties.Lang"

    Title="{x:Static language:Lang.bug_report}" Height="440" Width="900" Background="#ff80d3" ResizeMode="NoResize">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="55"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="5"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid Background="#ee63bb" Grid.Row="0">
        <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Padding="15, 0, 0, 0" FontSize="39.75" FontFamily="{StaticResource LeagueGothic}" Foreground="White">
            {x:Static language:Lang.found_bug}
        </TextBlock>
    </Grid>
    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="5"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="5"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="5"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid Grid.Column="0" Background="#ee63bb" />
        <Grid Grid.Column="1">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="45"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="5"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid>
                <TextBlock FontSize="28" FontFamily="{StaticResource LeagueGothic}" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                    Bug in the launcher
                </TextBlock>
            </Grid>
            <Grid Grid.Row="1" Background="#ee63bb"/>
            <Grid Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="10"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition Height="35"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition Height="71"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition Height="35"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition Height="92"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition Height="35"></RowDefinition>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="17.25" VerticalAlignment="Center" Background="#ee63bb" Padding="5">
                    <Italic><Bold>Do not</Bold> submit launcher bug reports to YandereDev.</Italic>
                </TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" TextWrapping="Wrap" TextAlignment="Justify" FontSize="15.25" Foreground="White" Padding="6, 3, 6, 3">
                    The Yandere Simulator launcher is an open-source project that is maintained by volunteers.
                    The project lead accepts bug reports by email at the following address:
                </TextBlock>
                <Grid Grid.Row="3">
                    <controls:OtherHyperlinkFromText LinkFontSize="25.75" IsDere="False" DisplayText="scott@loosescrew.ca" LinkedUrl="mailto:scott@loosescrew.ca" />
                </Grid>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="4" TextWrapping="Wrap" TextAlignment="Justify" FontSize="15.25" Foreground="White" Padding="6, 3, 6, 3">
                    Check out the status of reported bugs by looking at the project's issues tab on GitHub. If you have an account, you may also comment on issues, submit pull requests, and otherwise contribute to the launcher.
                </TextBlock>
                <Grid Grid.Row="5">
                    <controls:OtherHyperlinkFromText  LinkFontSize="25.75" IsDere="False" DisplayText="YandereSimulatorLauncher2 on GitHub" LinkedUrl="https://github.com/scottmichaud/yanderesimulatorlauncher2"/>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
        <Grid Grid.Column="2" Background="#ee63bb" />
        <Grid Grid.Column="3">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="45"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="5"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid Grid.Row="0">
                <TextBlock FontSize="28" FontFamily="{StaticResource LeagueGothic}" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                    Bug in the game
                </TextBlock>
            </Grid>
            <Grid Grid.Row="1" Background="#ee63bb"/>
            <Grid Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="4"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition Height="50"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition Height="35"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition Height="65"></RowDefinition>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="15.75" TextAlignment="Justify" Foreground="White" Padding="6, 3, 6, 3">
                    If the bug affects the game, not the launcher, then submit the game bug to YandereDev through his website.
                </TextBlock>
                <Grid Grid.Row="2">
                    <controls:OtherHyperlinkFromText LinkFontSize="25.75" IsDere="False" DisplayText="yanderesimulator.com/bug-reporting" LinkedUrl="https://yanderesimulator.com/bug-reporting/" />
                </Grid>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" TextWrapping="Wrap" TextAlignment="Center" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="15.75" VerticalAlignment="Center" Background="#ee63bb" Padding="5" Margin="5, 0, 5, 0">
                    <Italic><Bold>Do not</Bold> submit launcher bugs to the above link. <LineBreak/> &lt;-- Report bugs affecting the launcher on the left.</Italic>
                </TextBlock>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
        <Grid Grid.Column="4" Background="#ee63bb" />
    </Grid>
    <Grid Grid.Row="2" Background="#ee63bb"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: `xmlns` can specify namespace only and so I think `xmlns:language="clr-namespace:YandereSimulatorLauncher2.Properties.Lang"` would cause error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`{...}` are markupextensions syntax and only valid in attributes. Either do

```
<TextBlock Text="{x:Static language:Lang.found_bug}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Padding="15, 0, 0, 0" FontSize="39.75" FontFamily="{StaticResource LeagueGothic}" Foreground="White"/>
```

or

```
<TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Padding="15, 0, 0, 0" FontSize="39.75" FontFamily="{StaticResource LeagueGothic}" Foreground="White">
    <x:Static Member="language:Lang.found_bug"/>
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: Also, I would like to ask a question. But what about <Italic> and so on?

Comment: you mean `<TextBlock><Run FontStyle="Italic">some text</Run>`?